# Linguistics. German verbs

Tags: data-request, language

One might think that this question should be on the [StackExchange German](https://german.stackexchange.com/) site, but they appear not to like requests for lists and such like. Hence this post ...

I'm looking for large *electronic* list of German verbs with the following essential fields: infinitive, 3rd-person present indicative, 3rd-person simple past, and the past-participle. For example, in the case of the irregular verb, bringen, the list would have

> bringen, bringt, brachte, gebracht,

and in the case of the weak verb, sagen, the list would have

> sagen, sagt, sagte, gesagt.

I'm particularly looking for a list that separately lists verbs (where they exist) with the various separable and inseparable prefixes, such as

> ab-, an-, auf-, aus-, be- emp, ent-, er- ge-, miss-, ver- zer-,

etc.

I have been able to locate printed lists such as the Collins Pocket German Verb Tables (ISBN 000470153-4) which are quite comprehensive. However, aside from the disadvantage of not being in electronic form, the book does not list the parts I'm looking for. Instead, the body of the book consists of 200 example verbs to which some 2000 verbs are then cross-referenced. The wanted material is all there, but in a very awkward form for linguistic purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [verbs.csv](https://github.com/viorelsfetea/german-verbs-database/blob/master/output/verbs.csv) seems to be exactly what you are looking for. It includes 8049 verb with their associated conjugations. The list is part of the [german-verbs-database](https://github.com/viorelsfetea/german-verbs-database).

Answer (score 2):

Word forms available at Wiktionary

https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:bringen

You can parse page content using:

https://github.com/Suyash458/WiktionaryParser

You can also check GermaNet:
https://uni-tuebingen.de/en/142806